# JButton not enabling when Combo Box contain data in Java

Tags: java, swing, combobox

[image]

As above screenshot,

**1.When Item No Combo box is empty "Change Item No" button must be disabled.
When Name Combo box is empty "Change Drug Name" button must be disabled.**

**2.When Item No Combo box is not empty "Change Item No" button must be enabled. 
When Name Combo box is not empty "Change Drug Name" button must be enabled.**

For to do this, I created a method for disabling the buttons at the start;and called it for working;

```
//method setting the change ID and change drugname buttons disable at the start
private void disableBtns(){
    chg_itemIDbtn.setEnabled(false);
    chg_drugNamebtn.setEnabled(false);
}
```

In the "Change Item No" button action performed I coded this to enable button when combo box contain data;

```
private void chg_itemIDActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
   if(IDcombo.getItemCount()!=0){
       chg_itemIDbtn.setEnabled(true);
   }
}
```

But Button is not enabling;What is the error here?

Comment: did you click the button to enable combobox? and how can you click it if you disable buttons  at the start ?

Comment: ohh yes :( My mistake :( thanks @FastSnail I change it and now working..